# JQuery list selectors misbehave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I know a lot of people have asked questions about selectors, but whatever I do looks right but still ends up not working.  I have a list of actions.  The actions are shown or hidden whenever their "folder" is clicked.  I don't want them to hide again when the action itself is clicked...however they do.  Can anyone see what my problem is?  I've tried so many variations; maybe it's just late.

Relevant code:

func.js

```
$(function() {
    $(".menuitems").hide();

    $("#dmenu li").not(".menuitems li").click(function() {
        $(this).children(".menuitems").slideToggle();
    });

    $(".menuitems").children("li").click(function() {
        $.get("aux/" + $(this).text() + ".html", function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }, "text");
    });
});
```

main.html

```
<div id="content">
All contents come here!!
</div>

<div id="leftnavigation">
<h3>Options</h3>
<ul id="dmenu" style="list-style-type:none; margin-left:-50">
    <li>__Registration
        <ul class="menuitems">
            <li>FindExisting</li>
            <li>CreateNew</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to look on all li elements that has a .menuitems inside it you could do something like:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dmenu li:has(.menuitems)").click(function() {
        $(this).children(".menuitems").slideToggle();
    });
    $(".menuitems").hide().find("li").click(function() {
        $.get("aux/" + $(this).text() + ".html", function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }, "text");
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!  Why wouldn't the code I used work?  Do you know?  Also, how does adding `return false` affect the code?

Comment: return cancel the click event so it doesnt bubble down the node it will trigger the slideToggle if you remove return false statement.